# Which image is the answer?

Tags: cipher, visual, letters

[image]

Which of these four images is the result to the above and why?

Comment: can you tell me the name of that flower? maybe it will help me

Comment: @lois6b , Name of the flower: Allamanda cathartica

Comment: For the sake of completeness, which galaxy does that represent?

Comment: Would the `rebus` tag be appropriate too?

Comment: @QuestionAsker, I don't think so... but I've added a `cipher` tag, it was supposed to be one of the hints :)

Comment: @JamesCoyle It's Andromeda

Comment: Hmm.. that image looks like NGC 4414 to me, not Andromeda... ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer is

> ANDROMEDA. 
>  The picture of the strawberries clues "ROT" and the nautilus clues the Fibonacci sequence. So to decipher the grid, you use the ROT-n cipher on each letter, where n changes according to the Fibonacci sequence: 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21.

Comment: And we have a winner! :)

Comment: I was trying this technique for so long, but starting at 1 instead of 0. When you posted the latest comment to your question is when I realized what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Damnit. I knew as soon as it was confirmed as andromeda but didn't have time to write out the answer.

Comment: @C.Woods I thought of starting it from 1,1, but Fibonacci sequence starts with 0,1 according to Google, so decided to do it this way... Also chose Mona Lisa's image to mislead the people, don't know if it was a good idea, but it worked pretty well :))

Answer (score 2):

I, too think it's the Mona Lisa:

> Both the shape of the Nautilus Pompilius and distance/pattern of strawberry seeds are examples of the golden ratio, as is the Mona Lisa(and other Da Vinci Paintings AFAIK) (Partial credit to lois6b). The letter puzzle could be considered a code. I think the riddle refers to "The Da Vinci Code".

Comment: mhh what intrigues me is that, the letters are one part of the summation and the other part is RottenStrawberries together with shell..

Comment: A couple of hints for you: The solution is not related to Da Vinci. Different letters would result in a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say:

> The galaxy.

Because:

> It contains stars, which are small shiny points (like the small seeds in the strawberry), arranged in a spiral (like the shell) and their names usually contains Greek letters (like Alpha Centauri, Gamma Tauri and so on).

Comment: What about the letters?